# SQL Server Merge replication drop and creates subscriber table without any schema change

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

After adding table to replication it appears in `sysmergearticles` with status "6" and its not changing after sync, so replication always make drop/create table at subscriber. It started to appear suddenly and i have other tables that works good, but since several days i can't add table to publication without having this issue.

Comment: I've created new replication and all newly created tables has status of 6 in `sysmergearticles`. Only tables that were added to replication during it's creation works fine.

Comment: Are you using the -ParallelUploadDownload Merge Agent parameter by any chance?

Comment: Yes. Is it the reason of the problem?

Comment: We tested on test replication and on main with both 0 and 1 parameters for that property. The problem still exist.

Comment: Since all new tables in **test** replication has status "6" in `sysmergearticles` they all replicate without drop/recreation of tables. So, status 6 is not the case of the problem i think.